# BJT's Small signal Models

Tags: transistors

I'm trying to solve AC equivalent circuits of small signal BJT circuits. I'm confused whether to use the hybrid-pi or T-model.

Comment: Choice of small signal model to use will usually depend on the circuit you are trying to analyze, or perhaps the quantity you are trying to characterize (e.g. input resistance, output resistance). For example, the T model is often used when analyzing the common base amplifier configuration. Can you post a schematic of the circuit in question?

Comment: If you're worrying about the minutia of how a transistor operates in a circuit you're missing the point. Transistors vary enough that you should, for example, generally assume the gain is from some minimum value to infinity when designing the circuit. Show the schematic and we can show how to analyze it with whatever common sense is appropriate, regardless of what that may be called.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either model to analyze a small signal BJT circuit, but the hybrid-pi model is most commonly used. The T-model is supposedly easier to use in certain situations, but I've always used the hybrid-pi model without a problem.

The main difference between the two models is that the hybrid-pi model uses \$r_{\pi}\$ and the T-model uses \$r_e\$. Here's the relationship between the two:

$$r_{\pi} = \left( \beta + 1 \right) r_e$$

where \$\beta\$ is the gain of the transistor. On datasheets this may be \$h_{fe}\$.

Answer (score 0):

use pi model with common source transistor  without resistance ,common means connected directly to ground, otherwise, in every other case use the T model.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more why you prefer the T model in most cases?

Comment: We're talking about BJT's. There is no common source configuration for a BJT, since a BJT doesn't have a source terminal.